# behaviour of java.util.Date in deep copy

Tags: java, deep-copy, shallow-copy, java.util.date

I have Windows 7 Professional 64-bit operating system and I am working with JDK 7.

I have an Employee class which supports copying via constructor:

```
public class Employee {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private java.util.Date hireDate;

   public Employee() { 
   } 

   public Employee(Employee e) {
      this.id = e.id;
      this.name = e.name;
      this.hireDate = e.hireDate;
   }

   // getters and setters
}
```

To test first I create an employee1 object:

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee();
employee1.setId(1);
employee1.setName("John");
employee1.setHireDate(new GregorianCalendar(2018, Calendar.DECEMBER, 19).getTime());
```

Then I clone it to employee2 object;

```
Employee employee2 = new Employee(employee1);
```

Now I was told that only primitives and immutables dont need deep copying and since **`java.util.Date`** is neither primitive nor immutable so I was thinking it will act as a reference copying so if I change it in one object it would also automatically change in second object.

So I change it in 2nd object:

```
employee2.setHireDate(new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 5).getTime())
```

but when I print them both out:

```
System.out.println("employee1.getHireDate()=" + employee1.getHireDate());
System.out.println("employee2.getHireDate()=" + employee2.getHireDate());
```

I saw 2 different dates. What I have understand incorrectly?

Comment: `Date` is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand the internals.

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee();
employee1.setId(1);
employee1.setName("John");
employee1.setHireDate(new GregorianCalendar(2018, Calendar.DECEMBER, 19).getTime());
```

When you do this, you have an employee object, `employee1` which has a reference `hireDate` which is pointing to the `Date` object containing date (19/12/2018).

Now, when you did this:

```
Employee employee2 = new Employee(employee1);
```

Both objects `employee1` and `employee2` have reference `hireDate` which are pointing to the `Date` object containing date (19/12/2018).

Now, understand this:

```
employee2.setHireDate(new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 5).getTime());
```

When you do this, a new `Date` object is created by `new GregorianCalendar(2017, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 5).getTime()` and now, `hireDate` reference of object `employee2` points to this `Date` object. Not the previous one.

That means `hireDate` reference of object `employee1` points to `Date` object containing date (19/12/2018) and `hireDate` reference of object `employee2` points to `Date` object containing date (5/2/2017).

That's why you are getting different dates.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing each Employee’s hire date to a *new Date object,* so it makes sense that the two values are independent.

The problem is, after calling the copy constructor, they both share the *same Date instance,* which is mutable (via its [setTime method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#setTime%28long%29)).  If the Date object itself (not the Employee property) is changed by calling its setTime method, we can see the effect:

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee();
employee1.setId(1);
employee1.setName("John");
employee1.setHireDate(new GregorianCalendar(2018, Calendar.DECEMBER, 19).getTime());

Employee employee2 = new Employee(employee1);

// Change the state of the Date object shared by both instances.
employee2.getHireDate().setTime(
    new GregorianCalendar(2018, Calendar.JANUARY, 19).getTimeInMillis());

System.out.println("employee1.getHireDate()=" + employee1.getHireDate());
System.out.println("employee2.getHireDate()=" + employee2.getHireDate());
```

The solution is to perform defensive copying of the Date:

```
public Employee(Employee e) {
   this.id = e.id;
   this.name = e.name;
   this.hireDate = (e.hireDate != null ? (Date) e.hireDate.clone() : null);
}
```

Also, your getter and setter methods should do the same thing:

```
public Date getHireDate() {
    return hireDate != null ? (Date) hireDate.clone() : null);
}

public void setHireDate(Date newDate) {
    this.hireDate = (newDate != null ? (Date) newDate.clone() : null);
}
```

This way, the hire date cannot be changed except by calling your setHireDate method (or with reflection, but that’s a separate issue).  The Employee class has full control over its own data.